# connecting to Git via ssh on Windows fails

Tags: windows, git, ssh

While my Linux machines can access the hosted repositories on the NAS using its hostname, my Windows machine fails to access it from command line / Visual Studio Code. During my debugging attempts I found a way so that at least TortoiseGit can access the repositories: I had to add an env var `GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -vvv` (besides the already existing `GIT_SSH=C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitPlink.exe`).

When I issue a `git pull` via cmd for a repository accessed in Git config via `url = ssh://gituser@my-devices-hostname/volume1/git/reponame.git` I get the following output:

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "my-devices-hostname" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to my-devices-hostname [192.168.0.50] port 22.
getaddrinfo: atch: Name or service not known
ssh: connect to host my-devices-hostname port 22: failure
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

When I replace the hostname by a static IP I get the same error:

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.0.50 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.50 [192.168.0.50] port 22.
getaddrinfo: atch: Name or service not known
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.50 port 22: failure
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

When doing the same with TortoiseGit, everything works fine, I get:

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "my-devices-hostname" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to my-devices-hostname [192.168.0.50] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
...
```

I've recently set up a new DSL router (Fritz!Box 7590), maybe this is somehow related. Since I guessed that the problem could be related to IPv6, I've disabled IPv6 on the Synology NAS, but no change.

Update:
fedrik asked me to perform a manual ssh. Here are the results:

```
ssh gituser@my-devices-hostname
fatal: Interactive git shell is not enabled.
hint: ~/git-shell-commands should exist and have read and execute access.
Connection to my-devices-hostname closed.
```

and surprisingly:

```
ssh gituser@196.168.0.50
ssh: connect to host 196.168.0.50 port 22: Connection timed out
```

I updated my Git- and Tortoise installation, now I get

```
ssh gituser@192.168.0.50
fatal: Interactive git shell is not enabled.
hint: ~/git-shell-commands should exist and have read and execute access.
Connection to 192.168.0.50 closed.
```

The hostname based ssh remained the same.

Inspired by the answer from VonC, I checked if there are multiple instances of ssh installed on my system. I found the following:

```
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe
```

So I checked (after updating Tortoise and Git for Windows), which one is used. First, I left GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -vvv:

```
git pull
OpenSSH_8.4p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/c/Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/c/Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "my-devices-hostname" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to my-devices-hostname [192.168.0.50] port 22.
getaddrinfo: atch: Name or service not known
ssh: connect to host my-devices-hostname port 22: failure
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

"C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe" -vvv gituser@192.168.0.50
OpenSSH_8.4p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.0.50 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/c/Users/bjoer/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/c/Users/bjoer/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.50 [192.168.0.50] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
```

After I changed the env var: `GIT_SSH_COMMAND=C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe -vvv` I got this:

```
git pull
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/user/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolving "my-devices-hostname" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to my-devices-hostname [192.168.0.50] port 22.
getaddrinfo: atch: Der angegebene Host ist unbekannt.
ssh: connect to host my-devices-hostname port 22: failure
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -vvv gituser@192.168.0.50
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/user/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.0.50 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.50 [192.168.0.50] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
```

When I unset `GIT_SSH` and `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` env vars, I get this:

```
git pull
getaddrinfo: atch: Name or service not known
ssh: connect to host my-devices-hostname port 22: failure
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So, I can connect via SSH to the Git server, but when issues from the Git executable itself, it fails.
When I launch up a WSL on the same machine, I can perform a `git pull` without problems.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this issue?

Comment: This is some form of networking issue. Can also be caused by an old git version coupled with newer versions of supporting libraries - or the other way around. Since you're using Tortoise that can also be part of the cause. Can you do a plain `ssh` to the host?

Comment: Thanks for the tips, fredrik! I've incorporated my previous answer in the question for better readability.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting this error as a result of setting `git config --global ssh.variant plink`. By setting `git config --global ssh.variant ssh`, this error went way. The problem seems to be that git was passing a `-batch` option, which plink was interpreting as a `-b` option (hence the strange error involving "atch".

Answer (score 1):

Although this issue appeared somewhat after I installed a new router, the root cause was a defective setup of the Git server on my Synology NAS. After setting up the Git server from scratch following these steps, everything worked fine again:

#### Setup user and folder

- Install WebDAV package via Diskstation Package Manager
- Configure WebDAV: Enable HTTP on port 5005 and HTTPS on port 5006
- Control Panel -> File Services -> SMB -> Advanced Settings -> Set min and max SMB protocols to SMB1 and SMB3
- Create user `gituser` via Diskstation interface (group *users*, no access to shared folders, with File Station and WebDAV privilages)
- Add new shared folder called `git` (located at `/volume1/git`) with read/write access for `gituser`. This folder will hold all the repos.
- Install Git Server package via Diskstation
- Open Git Server and allow `gituser` permissions (one has to login as "admin" to see the available users)
- Enable SSH access on Diskstation (Control Panel > Terminal & SNMP > Enable SSH Service)
- Activate user home service (Control Panel > Users > Extended > Userbase > Activate user home service)

#### Configure SSH Access

- create `~/.ssh` folder for gituser on server

```
sudo su
mkdir /volume1/homes/gituser/.ssh
```

- create a private/public key pair via PuTTYgen (SSH-2 RSA, 2048 bits)
- copy the public key show at top of the window to a file named *authorized_keys*
- copy that file from local computer to gituser account on server

```
scp authorized_keys username@nas:/volume1/homes/gituser/.ssh
```

- change permissions while logged in as root

```
cd /volume1/homes/gituser/
sudo chown -R gituser:users .ssh
sudo chmod 700 .ssh
sudo chmod 644 .ssh/authorized_keys
sudo chmod 755 /volume1/homes/gituser
```

- activate public key SSH access by setting the following properties in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

- disable and then re-enabled the SSH service (Control Panel > Terminal & SNMP > Enable SSH Service)

Answer (score 0):

I would try the same ssh call without GIT_SSH set

```
set GIT_SSH=
```

With a recent Windows 10, openSSH is either directly installed or provided with [Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).
Make sure to use the latest version of Git, and add its `usr/bin` folder to your PATH.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! This led me to further investigations, which I documented in the original post. Seems that I've to versions of SSH installed, but no matter which one I use: I can always connect to the Git server via SSH, but a git pull always fails :(